# How to Convert the series of date to start and end date with regular entries in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame for which I want to transform the series of dates to start date and end date based on another variable.

Below is the Example:

```
Input = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-10-10', '2020-10-11', '2020-10-12'
                     , '2020-10-13', '2020-10-14'], 'groupby': ['AAA',
                     'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB']})
```

I need Output as below:

```
Output = pd.DataFrame({'StartDate': ['2020-10-10', '2020-10-13'],
                      'EndDate': ['2020-10-12', '2020-10-14'],
                      'groupby': ['AAA', 'BBB']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Output = pd.DataFrame()
Output['StartDate'] = Input.groupby('groupby')['date'].first()
Output['EndDate'] = Input.groupby('groupby')['date'].last()
Output

groupby StartDate   EndDate
AAA 2020-10-10  2020-10-12
BBB 2020-10-13  2020-10-14
```

EDIT: This fixes the sequential date issue.

```
Output = pd.DataFrame()
grp = Input.groupby((Input['groupby']!=Input['groupby'].shift()).cumsum())
Output['StartDate'] = grp['date'].first().reset_index(drop=True)
Output['EndDate'] = grp['date'].last().reset_index(drop=True)
Output['groupby'] = grp['groupby'].first().reset_index(drop=True)
Output

    StartDate   EndDate groupby
0   2020-10-10  2020-10-10  AAA
1   2020-10-11  2020-10-12  BBB
2   2020-10-14  2020-10-14  AAA
```

Comment: thanks but I think this wouldn't work if the date series is not in sequence

If my data looks like this:

`Input = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-10-10', '2020-10-11', '2020-10-12', '2020-10-14'], 'groupby': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'AAA']})` then my output for 'AAA' remains incorrect

Comment: Just for reference, I have solved this in R by using `data.table` module and `cumsum` function Example : `Input[, .(from = min(date), to = max(date)),  by = .(groupby, g = cumsum(c(0, diff(date)) != 1))]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `agg` function to find the `min` and `max` of the date. Then you can rename the columns to get the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-10-10', '2020-10-11', '2020-10-12'
                     , '2020-10-13', '2020-10-14'], 'groupby': ['AAA',
                     'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB']})

print (df)

df_result = (df.groupby('groupby').agg({'date':['min','max']})
               .reset_index()
               .droplevel(0, axis=1)
               .rename(columns={'':'groupby','min': 'StartDate','max':'EndDate'}))
print (df_result)
```

The output of this will be:

**Original dataframe:**

```
         date groupby
0  2020-10-10     AAA
1  2020-10-11     AAA
2  2020-10-12     AAA
3  2020-10-13     BBB
4  2020-10-14     BBB
```

**New dataframe with Start and End date**

```
  groupby  StartDate    EndDate
0     AAA  2020-10-10  2020-10-12
1     BBB  2020-10-13  2020-10-14
```